# Restcord API listGuildMembers

Tags: php, discord

Using restcord API when I call `listGuildMembers` it returns nothing. I am not sure about the third parameter

https://www.restcord.com/Guild/List%20Guild%20Members/

I called it by 3 different ways but same empty result

```
$users = $client->guild->listGuildMembers(['guild.id' => 451261315667853312, 'limit' => 25]);

$users = $client->guild->listGuildMembers(['guild.id' => 451261315667853312, 'limit' => 25, 'after'=>0]);

$users = $client->guild->listGuildMembers(['guild.id' => 451261315667853312, 'limit' => 25, 'after'=>450894467260743690]); //450894467260743690 this is guild_owner ID
```

I then downloaded the dev branch from restcode instead of live env. It solved my problem  i.e it started giving me the list of members but it is returning NULL on the email index. Screenshot is also attached. Kindly help if anyone have already fixed the same issue.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you have access to the user email unless you using OAuth

Comment: Yes you are right. Using OAuth I needed to get the access grant first then I got to fetch the email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok it turns out that Discord never returns email address of a user untill it is pre authenticated by the user. It was returning NUll because user of which I was trying to fetch email was never authenticated my script to fetch email.